# I am using Laravel I keep getting PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am using Laravel with Xampp. When I put http://127.0.0.1:8000 in the browser. I go to the Laravel home page but when I put http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin, I get a PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR.

This is the error;

An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8000. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

In Chrome, the error for http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin is This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection.

What do I do to rectify this error.

Comment: We need more info, can you provide code for your `/admin` route?

Comment: Always open your devtools in this case and check the network and console tabs of the browser after that go to your laravel.log and see if there are any errors

Answer (score 0):

I was losing my mind over this. It has been 2 days of trying to figure this out and I was failing miserably until I found a YouTube video with the answer.

So basically, first stop the server with ctrl + c, then go to the project folder and open the command prompt there. Then run `php artisan optimize`. After run the usual `php artisan serve` to start the server. Things should work fine now

Comment: This can be the case but it depends on per setup. So not a general solution